Is manually Powering Off a (worker) node a reliable way to test node failure?
I am wondering if manually powering off a worker node, is in fact a reliable (or even correct) way to try to mimic node failure?  Gracefully shutting down, does (as far as I can tell) NOT trigger K8s to go into any kind of recovery, or reallocation mode and sets the node to NotReady.  It is my opinion that a failure would trigger an UNgraceful shutdown, whereby K8s would then react and try to recover.
Is my understanding wrong?

Then don't shut it down gracefully; just yank the power cord.

There are multiple ways a hardware and software can fail:

no power
a component fails and the machine is not answering anymore
one of the storage volumes fails and some processes get stuck, but others no
the system is overloaded
the system is under a DoS/DDoS attack
software was not deployed uniformly across the "cluster"
a mount point gets full
someone unplugs the server, or plays with the power cord
someone stops a service but not all on one of the nodes
network issues: availability, packet loss, congestion, silent packet corruption, MTU issues, high latency
X509 SSL/TLS certificate issues (expired, untrusted, non standard compliant)
missing backups. missing monitoring or, worse, non working ones.

This is just a short list. If it can happen, it will happen at one moment in time.
